# Cannot Emit Either.Left in Flow because of type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, either

Here I have i function that gets some data. I use Either for sending data to ViewModel.

```
sealed class Either<out L, out R> {
    /** * Represents the left side of [Either] class which by convention is a "Failure". */
    data class Left<out L>(val a: L) : Either<L, Nothing>()

    /** * Represents the right side of [Either] class which by convention is a "Success". */
    data class Right<out R>(val b: R) : Either<Nothing, R>()
}
```

How can I emit error data in catch block?

```
fun getStocksFlow(): Flow<Either<Throwable, List<Stock>>> = flow {
        val response = api.getStocks()
        emit(response)
    }
        .map {
            Either.Right(it.stocks.toDomain())
        }
        .flowOn(ioDispatcher)
        .catch { throwable ->
            emit(Either.Left(throwable)) //Here it shows Type mismatch, it needs Either.Right<List<Stock>>
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow transforms to `Flow<Right<Throwable, List<Stock>>>` after `.map` applying, so trying to emit value of `Either.Left` type to flow of `Either.Right` is wrong cause `Either.Left` doesn't match `Either.Right` type. Cast `Either.Right(it.stocks.toDomain())` to `Either<Throwable, List<Stock>>` should fix that.